# How can one connect a button to a database that saves new entry in python using pyqt?

Tags: python, database, button, pyqt

This is the code for the submit button that is suppose to save entries in the database. Nothing saves when data is entered and it just does nothing.

```
class Register(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Register, self).__init__(parent)
        uic.loadUi("C:\\Users\\Li\\Desktop\\GUI\\LIC\\Register.ui", self)
        self.show()
        self.regbtn.clicked.connect(self.page)

    def page(self):
        firstname = self.Fname.text()
        lastname = self.Lname.text()
        address = self.address.text()
        email = self.Email.text()
        phone = self.phone.text()
        password = self.password.text()
        print(firstname,lastname,address,email,phone,password)
        # getting the currently selected radio button
        if self.male.isChecked():
            gender = 'Male'
        else:
            gender = 'Female'
        print(gender)

        # saving all the information entered into the database
        try:
            cur.execute('INSERT into Details(FirstName,LastName,Address,Gender,Email,PhoneNo,Password) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',(firstname,lastname,address,gender,email,phone,password))
            db.commit()
        except:
            print("Not successful, Try again")
```

Comment: With "it just does nothing" do you mean that the function is not called at all? Also, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (at least including the UI creation and the button connection).

Comment: When i mean "it just does nothing" the data is not saved and page refuses to close unles i force stop.

Comment: @LisaChukwu change to `except Exception as e:` `print("Not successful, Try again", e)`